# How to construct target objective function for gradient descent?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, error-function, gradient-descent

I have a set of scores from two traits. After applying simple sum rule for fusion i.e. $f_{s}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i s_i$, fused score is achieved. From the fused score, I need to evaluate EER (equal error rate). EER is a point where false accept rate (FAR) and false reject rate (FRR) holds equality.

How do I construct the objective function to minimize EER? How do i apply gradient descent to estimate optimal weights for my problem?

Comment: The question is rather ambiguous I'm afraid. What estimator did you use, and what are the ground truth? Do you have a formula defining the FAR and FRR?

Comment: @YiningWang FRR=\frac{1}{m^{-}}\sum_{j=1}^{m^{-}}1_{g\left (x_{j}^{-} \geq \Gamma \right )}   \\  
FAR=\frac{1}{m^{+}}\sum_{i=1}^{m^{+}}1_{g\left (x_{i}^{+} <  \Gamma \right )}

Comment: @YiningWang EER is the point where FAR and FRR holds equality